# puzzling recursion with java

Tags: java

Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the largest substring which starts and ends with sub and return its length.

```
strDist("catcowcat", "cat") → 9
strDist("catcowcat", "cow") → 3
strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat") → 9
```

my solution

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    int i = sub.length();
    int j = str.length();
    int count = 0;
    if (str.length() == 1 && str.equals(sub)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (str.length() < sub.length() || str.length() <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (str.substring(0, i).equals(sub)) {
        if (str.substring(str.length() - i, str.length()).equals(sub)) {
            return str.length();
        } else {
            strDist(str.substring(0, str.length() - i), sub);
        }
    } else {
        strDist(str.substring(1, str.length()), sub);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

tell me how to correct my code?

Comment: This looks like the perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: First of all indent properly your code to better see scope of methods/code bocks/variables. This is great help while tracking bugs.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292131/1075247/

Comment: thnx buddy......m amature in coding

Comment: I formatted your code to be more readable. Note you have there variables that you never use `j` and `count`.

Comment: hey @Pshemo....tell me how can i improve my coding abilities??

Comment: Well, start by telling us what it's doing wrong. Does it crash? Wrong output? What's the problem?

Comment: @HenryKeiter.....last line return 0 execute most of time.....ideally it shouldnt

Answer (score 1):

Why does this need to be done with recursion?

**Edit**: fixed code to handle case where sub is not present in str, or only present once.

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  int last=str.lastIndexOf(sub);
  if (last != -1) {
    int first=str.indexOf(sub);
    if (first != last)
      return last - first + sub.length();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Recursion is great, if it is suited to the problem.  In this case, recursion doesn't add value, and writing it with recursion for the sake of recursion makes the code inefficient.

Comment: It may have been a homework exercise, hence the "need" to compute it with recursion.

Comment: try to run ur code with input as strDist("xyx", "z")....it will give wrong result......becoz problem asked to be solved by recursion    @trenin

Comment: Just check if last or first == -1, then the string doesn't exist, and return 0.

Comment: Be aware using recursion may cause heart-ache in the form of an unexpected run-time stack-overflow should the string ever be unduly long!

Answer (score 1):

This will , "compute recursively the largest substring which starts and ends with sub and return its length" as you described.

```
public class PuzzlingRecursion {

    static String substringFound = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "catcowcat";
        String substring = "cat";

        int sizeString = findNumberOfStrings(sentence, substring, 0);
        System.out.println("you are searching for: " + substring);
        System.out.println("in: " + sentence);
        System.out.println("substring which starts and ends with sub and return its length is:"+substringFound + ", " + sizeString);

    }

    private static int findNumberOfStrings(String subStringPassed,
            String setenecePassed, int count) {

        if (subStringPassed.length() == 0) {
            return count + 0;
        }
        if (subStringPassed.length() < setenecePassed.length()) {
            return count + 0;
        }
        count++;
        String lastStringMiddle = subStringPassed.replaceAll("(.*?)" + "("
                + setenecePassed + ")" + "(.*?)" + "(" + setenecePassed + ")"
                + "(.*?.*)", "$3");
        if (subStringPassed.contains(setenecePassed)
                && lastStringMiddle.length() != setenecePassed.length()) {
            if (subStringPassed.contains(setenecePassed)
                    && lastStringMiddle.contains(setenecePassed)) {
                // only found one item no pattern but according to the example
                // you posted it should return the length of one word/substring
                count = setenecePassed.length();
                substringFound = subStringPassed;
                return count;
            }
        }
        // makesure the lastSrtringMiddle has the key we are search
        if (!lastStringMiddle.equals(subStringPassed)) {
            subStringPassed = subStringPassed.replaceFirst(setenecePassed, "");
            String lastString = subStringPassed.substring(0,
                    subStringPassed.lastIndexOf(setenecePassed));
            if (null != lastString && !"".equals(lastString)) {
                count = lastStringMiddle.length() + setenecePassed.length()
                        + setenecePassed.length();
                substringFound = setenecePassed + lastStringMiddle
                        + setenecePassed;
                subStringPassed = "";
            }
            return findNumberOfStrings(subStringPassed, setenecePassed, count);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much nicer recursive solution:

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  if (str.length()==0) return 0;
  if (!str.startsWith(sub))
      return strDist(str.substring(1),sub);
  if (!str.endsWith(sub))
    return strDist(str.substring(0,str.length()-1),sub);
  return str.length();
}
```